# How to add template suggestions for form elements of a certain form ID?

Tags: 8, theming, forms, hooks

I'm looking to edit some Twig templates for certain form elements, but I need template suggestions only for certain form IDs. How do I go about that?

I currently have the following functions in my .theme file:

```
function exmaple_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    // Something here to alter suggestions of form elements only for the form with the ID 'user_register_form'
  }
}

function example_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#id'])) {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . str_replace('-','_', $variables['element']['#id']);
    // This works but returns global form element suggestions
    // For example 'form-element--edit-mail.html.twig' which affects all email edit form elements
    // I need suggestions like 'form-element--user-register-form--edit-mail.html.twig'
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle or observe how they solved it.

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of tricky as you'd have to write a lot of custom code to pass the form id to a form element as you stated above.  Fortunately, there is a contrib module called "[Themable forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms)" which does exactly that, both for form elements and form element labels.

So for example, if I am on the user login page, for the form elements, I see these default theme hooks for all individual form fields.

```
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/mytheme/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->

<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/mytheme/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
```

Note, there is no granularity at all for the above.

Now, after I enable *Themable forms*, I start to see very granular theme hook suggestions being output in the form of

```
  form-element--[form-id]--[element-type].html.twig
  form-element--form-id--[form-id].html.twig
  form-element--type--[element-type].html.twig
  form-element.html.twig
```

So for example, with the username field, I now see

```
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * form-element--user-login-form--textfield.html.twig
   * form-element--form-id--user-login-form.html.twig
   * form-element--type--textfield.html.twig
   x form-element.html.twig
-->

<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * form-element-label--user-login-form--textfield.html.twig
   * form-element-label--form-id--user-login-form.html.twig
   * form-element-label--type--textfield.html.twig
   x form-element-label.html.twig
-->
```

You'll now note a few things, the form id in the form element suggestion as well as the name of the form element itself.

This should get you where you want to be according to your question above.

You can install the module with:

```
composer require drupal/themable_forms
```

Comment: For anyone curious, I've done a comparison of Formdazzle and Themable Forms modules here: https://www.drupal.org/i/3278319   Themable Forms is enough to address this specific Stack Exchange question, however you might as well go with Formdazzle which adds more, better suggestions for other elements like form.html.twig and input.html.twig