# Drupal 8 Theme suggestions for form children elements

Tags: 8, theming

What is the best way to define template name suggestions for children elements of form in drupal 8?

In `myTheme.theme` I can define hook like this:

```
function myTheme_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form' & !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {
   $suggestions[] = 'form__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']  ['#id']);
  }
}
```

Which gives suggestions:

```
form--form-id.html.twig
form.html.twig
```

I want to define template names for all elements inside my form with id of the form as part of name suggestion. For example:

```
form-element--form-id.html.twig
form-element.html.twig
```

**Edit:** I understand there is a plugin for that. But I would preffer programmatic solution for better customization in future and also to not be completely dependend on external plugin functionality.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/302423/how-to-add-template-suggestions-for-form-elements-of-a-certain-form-id I can't vote to close this issue as a duplicate of that one because that one doesn't have an accepted answer unfortunately.